# Bootloader Installation failed, Android X86, Virtual Box

Tags: boot, virtualbox, installation, android, android-x86

I am trying to use Android x86 8.1 in Virtual Box using Ubuntu 18.04 as a Host OS, the problem is that once it is installed, if I send the shutdown signal, and then shut down the system ...

[image]
[image]

When I start the virtual machine again, it boots from the Live CD, instead of the local disk (so I have to install the system again)
[image]

In the Live CD, there is an option under "Advanced Options", that allows you to boot from local disk, but when I select that one, I have this problem

[image]

I guess, one solution might be do not power off the virtual machine and just save the machine state .. But, I would like to know if there is a solution for powering it off without having to install it again every time you shut it down

Edit:
I also try to eject the disk this way:
[image]

But I continue having this problem:
[image]

Comment: Why not set the boot disk to the local disk in VirtualBox? And/or eject the virtual CD?

Comment: How do I do that? .. I tought the same thing, but I couldn't find it on "settings", so, I don't know where is it ..

Comment: Open the properties of the VM in the VirtualBox GUI and adapt as wanted.

Comment: If I eject the Virtual CD, I still have an issue .. I edited the post

Comment: Bootloader installation failed - this is not a VirtualBox problem.

Comment: So, is it Android x86 8.1 problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed it .. It was so simple .. The file system must be ext4 .. ntfs and fat32 won't work ..
[image]
And then it is proceed with the normal installation
[image]
Be sure to eject the virtual CD, and you shouldn't have problem booting it from GRUB
[image]